# Model::create($dataarray) removes random row of data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel's Model::create() function to create a new entry in my database, but the array i'm passing into the function fails because it deletes one of the rows.

This is my array `All static`. This also matches what my database table looks like.

```
$data = [
    'terminal_id' => 222,
    'batch_id' => 1,
    'transactiondate' => '2323',
    'store' => '2323',
    'hostcode' => '2323',
    'pan' => '2323',
    'operation' => '2323',
    'posdatacode' => '2323',
    'amount' => '2323',
    'currency' => '2323',
    'acquirer' => '2323',
    'scheme' => '2323',
    'attemptsconn' => '2323',
    'transactionresult' => '2323',
    'merchantcode' => '2323',
    'terminal' => '2323'
];
```

And the line to insert it into the database

```
Transaction::create($data);
```

SQL error code when running this code:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'amount' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `transactions` (`terminal_id`, `batch_id`, `transactiondate`, `store`, `hostcode`, `pan`, `operation`, `posdatacode`, `currency`, `acquirer`, `scheme`, `attemptsconn`, `transactionresult`, `merchantcode`, `terminal`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

Now, if you look through the code, you'll notice the `amount` section of the array has gone missing.

### What have i tried:

- Formatting the entry code to `Transaction::create(['row' => 'value'])` instead of what i was doing. This returns same result.
- Creating a new transaction by doing `new Transaction` and then `$transaction->value` to insert the data. THIS WORKS.

I must be missing something obvious since this doesn't work. Please help me out.

Comment: Are all the values set as fillable in your `$fillable` array inside your `Transaction` model?

Comment: @Liam As i said,  I was missing something obvious. Thank you a s#$!ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Liam suggested the `"amount"` field was not in my `$fillable` array in the Model.

Code works flawlessly after inserting that value into the array.

Please upvote Liam's comment if you had an error like this, no need to answer this further.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> "Field 'amount' doesn't have a default value"

comes due to 
you can not set a default value for amount field in the database when the field amount is missing from the array, error throw.
So set the default value or set Null.

Comment: This error occured because of the data not being sent through, hence his question why there is no value being passed.